# Rotating a plane defined by a normal and a distance from the origin around an arbitrary point in 3D space

Tags: matrices, geometry, vector-spaces, 3d, rotations

I have a plane defined by its normal and its distance from the origin. I have a rotation matrix and a point in 3D space around which to do the rotation.

What formula will allow me to do the rotation?

Comment: How about you just post the question...?

Comment: I'm new here and as I was searching for the answer I was looking for, I noticed most titles took this form rather than an actual question. Almost all the titles actually.

Comment: @Nameless I think I misunderstood your comment. Anyway, I am trying to find an algorithm to rotate a plane around an arbitrary point for a computer program. I don't have any specific question. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the equation of the plane be
$$
\textbf{a}^T\textbf{x} = b
$$
where $\textbf{a}$ is a unit vector normal to the plane and b is the plane's distance from the origin.

Transform to a coordinate system centred on a point $\textbf{r}$:
$$
\textbf{x}' = \textbf{x} -\textbf{r}
$$
Then in the dashed coordinate system:
$$
 \textbf{a}^T(\textbf{x}' + \textbf{r}) = b
 \\ \textbf{a}^T\textbf{x}' = b - \textbf{a}^T\textbf{r}
$$
In this coordinate system apply the rotation to $\textbf{a}$:
$$
\textbf{a}^T\,\textbf{M}^T\textbf{x}' = b - \textbf{a}^T\textbf{r}
$$
Then transform back to get the equation of the rotated plane in the original coordinate system:
$$
\textbf{a}^T\textbf{M}^T(\textbf{x} - \textbf{r})= b - \textbf{a}^T\textbf{r}
\\ \textbf{a}^T\textbf{M}^T\,\textbf{x} = b - \textbf{a}^T\textbf{r} + \textbf{a}^T\textbf{M}^T\,\textbf{r}
$$

Comment: Thanks. What does a T top right from a letter means? For example, what does the T means in the first line aTx =b ?

Comment: The transpose of the matrix or vector.

Comment: Is there something missing in the 4th equation (aTMTx′=b−aTr)? I can't understand why this equation and the only above could both hold true if MT isn't an identity matrix. Either that or there is something I don't understand.

Comment: In that equation the vector a has been rotated, so x' is not the same as in the equation above. (It could be given a different symbol if you prefer.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't learned how to read math above algebra. I'm new to sentences like "Let..., where.... apply..." so thanks for your help. In the 4th equation, both a and x' are different than in the 3rd, then in the 5th, a has yet another value, as well as b, is that right?

Comment: No, after the equation discussed above the symbols keep their meanings with the exception of x, which now represents a different set of solutions as a result of the rotation of the plane.